# What is wrong with this PHP function for Woocommerce Cart?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I created a function for adding a fee to the Woocommerce cart. It works partially, but displays the lowest fee. It just ignores the condition of <= 550 and the highest fee. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

```
function verzendkosten( $cart_object ) {

    global $woocommerce;
    $laag = 37.50;
    $hoog = 57.50;
    $vala = 550.00;
    $prijs = $woocommerce->cart->total;

    if($prijs <= $vala) {

        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Verzendkosten', $hoog, true, 'standard' );
    }

    if($prijs > $vala) {

        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Verzendkosten', $laag, true, 'standard' );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'verzendkosten' );
```

Comment: What is in $prijs?You can use `if(bccomp($prijs, $vala)) == -1` http://php.net/manual/en/function.bccomp.php

Comment: Should be the numeric value of the carts total. It's in Dutch, so this would be the translation:

$laag = low (as in lowest fee), 
$hoog = high (as in highest fee), 
$prijs = numeric output of woocommerce cart total, 
$vala = "Value A" which in this case is 550. 'Cause I want the fees to switch when the carts total hits a certain price.

Comment: Mihai, that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Probably issues relating to comparing int with decimals,just a general hint.Thats why I was asking what is in $prijs,what value

Comment: I get a server error when I use the snippet you gave. With and without decimals.

Comment: Couldn't figure it out, so I used another solution.